# Am i right in determining the pressure being applied to the below side of the plate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

In the image shown below the an iron plate is dividing the cylinder into two halves with 15 meter and 1 meter respectively.[image]

The area of the cylinder is 0.196 m(sq).The liquid inside the cylinder is water.Height of the cylinder is 16 meters.

We know that the

Pressure = density of water X acceleration due to gravity X height

for the above region it comes out to be:

Pressure = 1000 X 10 X 15

```
     = 150000 N m(sq)
```

So this will be the pressure applied on the above part of the plate

But for the case of finding the pressure being applied from the downwards will the height be considered as 16 or something else.

Comment: How was this system put together? Is the plate a movable piston? How was air excluded?

Comment: After the plate was inserted the water level in the above portion increased same to that of the volume of the plate.i guess that answered your question. Else just suppose that there is no air gap between the below portion of the plate and the water touching it.

Answer (score 1):

If the plate and cylinder are rigid, there is not enough information to answer.  The container below the plate is basically a pressure vessel.  The water within that vessel could be at virtually any pressure.  It is disconnected from the upper container by the strength of the iron plate.  This strength means the upper and lower pressures don't have a fixed relationship.

Comment: The plate was not there earlier but then it was slided in that position

Comment: If the plate is inserted in some way that doesn't change the pressures, then you can just solve for the case where the plate isn't there.

Comment: So supposing that if the height of the plate is about 5 cm the to calculate the pressure exerted on the lower surface I will take height to be (15+0.05 )m